# DynamoDB/CF - Subscriber limit exceeded: Only 10 tables can be created, updated, or deleted simultaneously

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cloudformation, serverless-framework

I was trying to create 24 DynamoDB tables using serverless.yml when I got below error. How do I circumvent this?

```
Serverless: Checking Stack update progress…
.................................................................Serverless: Deployment failed!

Serverless Error ---------------------------------------

 An error occurred while provisioning your stack: TestUserTable
 - Subscriber limit exceeded: Only 10 tables can be created,
 updated, or deleted simultaneously.
Your Environment Information -----------------------------
OS: linux
Node Version: 6.6.0
Serverless Version: 1.1.0
```

This seems to be a general issue with Cloudformation, Here is a workaround in the AWS forum: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=167996

I tried adding `dependson` but it still does not solve the issue.

I get following error

```
ServerlessError: Template format error: Unresolved resource dependencies [Dev1ProductTables] in the Resources block of the template
```

Putting `DependsOn: "DevPolicyTable"` in quotes also does not make any difference

```
resources:
  Resources:
    DevUserTable: 
      Type: "AWS::DynamoDB::Table"
      DependsOn: DevPolicyTable
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions: 
          - AttributeName: "id"
            AttributeType: "S"
        KeySchema: 
          - AttributeName: "id"
            KeyType: "HASH"
        ProvisionedThroughput: 
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        TableName: "b1-dev-user"
      DevPolicyTable: 
        Type: "AWS::DynamoDB::Table"
        DependsOn: DevClaimTable
        Properties: 
          AttributeDefinitions: 
            - AttributeName: "id"
              AttributeType: "S"
          KeySchema: 
          - AttributeName: "id"
          KeyType: "HASH"
          ProvisionedThroughput: 
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
          TableName: "b1-dev-policy"
```

Comment: It looks `Dev1ProductTables` is missing from the code sample you shared. Can you share the entire file and fix the formatting?

Comment: did you ever figure it out? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: Using DependsOn should help. You basically put a dependency for each table to be dependent on other and make a chain so that at any given point in time only 1 table is being created and not all in parallel. This should help.

Comment: Consider combining your tables using the single table design pattern.

Answer (score 1):

You're exceeding number of tables created in parallel, the easiest way to fix it is using DependsOn. You can set a table dependency into another table  so this table won't be created until the creation of the depending table.

In this example table 1 won't be created until table 2 is already created so they're not created in parallel.

```
"Table1": {
      "Type": "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
      "DependsOn": [
        "Table2"
      ],
      "Properties": {
        "AttributeDefinitions": [
          {
            "AttributeName": "key",
            "AttributeType": "S"
          }
        ],
        "KeySchema": [
          {
            "AttributeName": "key",
            "KeyType": "HASH"
          }
        ],
        "ProvisionedThroughput": {
          "ReadCapacityUnits": "2",
          "WriteCapacityUnits": "2"
        },
        "TableName": {
          "table1"
        }
      }, 
"Table2": {
      "Type": "AWS::DynamoDB::Table",
      "Properties": {
        "AttributeDefinitions": [
          {
            "AttributeName": "key",
            "AttributeType": "S"
          }
        ],
        "KeySchema": [
          {
            "AttributeName": "key",
            "KeyType": "HASH"
          }
        ],
        "ProvisionedThroughput": {
          "ReadCapacityUnits": "2",
          "WriteCapacityUnits": "2"
        },
        "TableName": {
          "table2"
        }
      }
```